# Mysql stored function returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, decimal, stored-functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION cleanAmount(amount DECIMAL)
    RETURNS decimal(30,2)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE res DECIMAL;
SET res=CAST(COALESCE(amount,0.00) AS DECIMAL(30,2));
RETURN res;
END
```

`SELECT cleanAmount('3.456');` return 3,00. It should be 3,46

Comment: Try `ROUND` instead of `CAST`? eg: `ROUND(3.456,2)`

Comment: `SET res=ROUND(amount,2);` returns 3,00. `SELECT CAST(COALESCE(3.456,0.00) AS DECIMAL(30,2))` returns 3.46 :s

Comment: Even changing that line to SET res=amount; returns 3.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declare of res in the stored proc:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION cleanAmount(amount DECIMAL(60,30))
    RETURNS decimal(30,2)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE res DECIMAL(30,2);
SET res=CAST(COALESCE(amount,0.00) AS DECIMAL(30,2));
RETURN res;
END
```

Comment: I have tried but doesn't changed. `DECLARE res DECIMAL(30,2);`

Comment: Try also changing the input parameter declare (I had that changed as well on mine when I tested it). I have edited my answer now to show this.

Answer (score 1):

default decimal is probably rounding your number

DECLARE res DECIMAL(30,2)